# Run SimpleOBEXClient/Server LightAquaBlue on OS X Yosemite 10.10

Tags: architecture, bluetooth, xcode6, iobluetooth, obex

I have managed to install LightAquaBlue 0.4 (http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/LightAquaBlue/) through the command

```
python setup.py install
```

However, I have tried to build with Xcode 6.0 both projects SimpleOBEXClient/Server contained in the folder /example.

The error is:

```
BBBluetoothOBEXClient.d Dtrace Error: expected predicate and/or actions following the probe
```

The details are:

```
VALID_ARCHS: i386 x86-64
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to fix the issue deleting the framework "LightAquaBlue" from the Tab General --> Linked Frameworks and Libraries and then re-installing the same framework by doing:

```
--> Click "+" below in the left corner;
--> Click "Add other";
--> Go to "/Library/Frameworks";
```

If you have successfully managed to install light blue 0.4 you should have the framework called "LightAquaBlue.framework".

```
--> Add this framework and go to the SimpleOBEXClient/Server.m;
--> Re-type the #import <LightAquaBlue/LightAquaBlue.h> line again.
```